# How to tell CMake when using add_library to not include a specific object file

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, gsoap

I am trying to make a static library, for example `my_lib.a`.
This library is depending from a gSoap code - `file2.cpp.o`, which is generated because of this CMake instruction (and 2 custom commands):

```
add_library(${TARGET_NAME} ${SRC_FILES}
    ${GENERATED_SRC_FILES} ${GENERATED_H_FILES} ${GENERATED_RES_FILES})
```

`file2.cpp` is present in `GENERATED_SRC_FILES`. Everything runs fine until the moment of linking.

> /usr/bin/ar cr ../lib/my_lib.a CMakeFiles/my_lib.dir/src/file1.cpp.o
>   CMakeFiles/my_lib.dir/src/file2.cpp.o

If I let Make to use this command, the library `my_lib.a` will contain
`file1.cpp.o` and `file2.cpp.o`. But in fact I do not need the `file2.cpp.o`
in my *.a library.

Does anyone know how I have to manage this case in a way to obtain a `my_lib.a` which contains only the `file1.cpp.o`?

Comment: I would write a macro that removes `file2.cpp` from  `${GENERATED_SRC_FILES}`

Comment: Or maybe just list(REMOVE_ITEM GENERATED_SRC_FILES file2.cpp)

Comment: Thank you for the ideas ! :)
I tried using the "list(..)" just before invoking the add_library() but it does not have a influence to the linking state...
What you mean by creating a macro ?
When I check the content of GENERATED_SRC_FILES, it contains the .cpp/.c files but not the object files *.o. Which means, for me, that the linking is completely different procedure...

Comment: If you remove the cpp file from the list then it will not be compiled as part of the library so you do not have to worry about .o files.

Comment: I saw what is a macro in CMake, I was not aware about this feature :) thank you for the idea, I will try it.

Comment: About the list remove_idem, yes I have the same thinking but unfortunately the result is not what I am expecting.. the *.o is always included in the *.a file.

Comment: I would delete the binary folder and reconfigure and regenerate in CMake and then rebuild.

Comment: I think I found a solution.
The idea is to compile some *.o files with a different target which will not be the official one. Than in the official target you can put these files you consider as important ones. In my case I have only one file that I do not want to include in the *.a file.. So :

the first target is:

add_library(gSoap_files OBJECT ${GENERATED_SRC_FILES} ... )

and the official one is:

add_library(${TARGET_NAME} ${SRC_FILES})

I inspired myself from this page:

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.
The idea is to compile some *.o files with a different target which will not be the official one. Than in the official target you can put these files you consider as important ones. In my case I have only one file that I do not want to include in the *.a file.. So :

the first target is:

add_library(gSoap_files OBJECT ${GENERATED_SRC_FILES} ... )

and the official one is:

add_library(${TARGET_NAME} ${SRC_FILES})

I inspired myself from this page:

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library